# A function whose inverse relation is not a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, relations, equivalence-relations

I need to come up with a function $f:X \to X$ where $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ whose inverse relation is not the function $X \to X$. I’ve tried with for example $f(x)=|x|$, but this clearly doesn’t work.

Comment: I assume that the function need not be surjective (that is, not all values of $X$ need appear in the range). Can you come up with a function that is not surjective? ¶ Incidentally, `$X \to X$` gives $X \to X$.

Comment: When you define a function you don't necessarily have to write it with an algebraic formula. You can just define it by saying $f(1)$ is this, $f(2)$ is that, and so on.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek ohhhh so I could have a function defined by let’s say f(1)=2, f(2)=2, f(3)=4, f(4)=1 and f(5)=3 and the inverse relation of this function wouldn’t be a function since we get 2 different values for f(2)?

Comment: @luna Yes. The inverse relation can only be a function if the original function is injective.

Comment: @luna Yes. Although to be precise you should say that you would get 2 values for $f^{-1}(2)$ (inverse of $f$, if there was one), not $f(2)$

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek right, thank you!

Comment: With the comments already stating that the formula is not necessary , you can make the $(x,y)$ pairs to get the function. If you still want a formula function , you can try $f(x)=|x-3|$ which will have 2 inverses for 2 values [(1,2),(5,2)] & [(2,1),(4,1)] , with $f(3)=0$ having 1 inverse

Comment: How about $f(x) = x^2 \pmod{5}$, with the qualification that $(5)$ is used in place of the congruence class represented by $(0)$.  Then, (for example) $f(1) = f(4)$.  This example was inspired by the analagous $$g:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} ~: ~g(x) = x^2.$$

Comment: Now that we go into algebraic formulas, of course $f(x)=1$ universally works.

Comment: @Prem but the function you mentioned doesn’t have the same domain and range, since 0 is not an element in X

Comment: Oh , then add 1 to that value : [$f(x)==|x-3|+1$] , @luna

Comment: @Prem perfect, thank you! Is there an easy way to write the inverse relation of this function?

Comment: You can try $f^{-1}(x)=3 \pm (f(x)-1)$ where the $\pm$ will give 2 values , in general.

Comment: In the Example function & the Inverse , you can check $x=1$ to get $f(x)=3$ to then get $f^{-1}(3)=3\pm(3-1)$ which will give 2 values $1,5$ (( Like-wise , you can check $x=2$ to get 2 values $2,4$. Hence the Inverse is not a function )) @luna

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy example$$f(x)=1+|3-x|$$

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take an ambiguous expression, such as the ln, and then invert that into a unique one, which is then your function.

e.g.:

$$
\begin{align*}
k &\in \mathbb{Z}\\
f&: \left\{1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5 \right\} \to \left\{1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5 \right\}\\
f(x) &= e^{2 \cdot k \cdot x \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i}} = e^{2 \cdot x \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i}} = \cos(2 \cdot k \cdot x \cdot \pi) + \sin(2 \cdot k \cdot x \cdot \pi) \cdot \mathrm{i} = 1\\
f^{-1}(x) &= \frac{\ln(x)}{2 \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i}} = \frac{2 \cdot k \cdot x \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i}}{2 \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i}} = k \cdot x
\\
\\
f(x) &= 1\\
f^{-x}(f(x)) &= k \cdot x
\end{align*}
$$

You can also just look up an inverse of a function that isn't a function such as arctan2, where the inverse of the inverse of the function is the function itself.

e.g.

$$
\begin{align*}
k &\in \mathbb{Z}\\
f&: \left\{1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5 \right\} \to \left\{1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5 \right\}\\
f(x) &= \tan(\pi \cdot x + \frac{\pi}{4}) = 1\\
f^{-1}(x) &= \frac{\arctan2(x, x)}{\pi} - \frac{1}{4} + 1\\
\\
f(x) &= 1\\
f^{-x}(f(x)) &= 1 + k\\
\end{align*}
$$